# Android Studio failed to build an APK

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'F:\ANDROID\Android Master\Artificial-Intelligence-Android-master\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\v4'.

Comment: Android devices don't have drives, nor do they use backslashes in paths.

Comment: @SLaks - but Android Studio on a Windows machine may know both. This sometimes happens to me and then I do what the IDE failed to do: delete the mentioned folder under the "app\build\generated\source\" folder

Comment: What does this error come from? Android or your build?

Comment: delete the `'F:\ANDROID\Android Master\Artificial-Intelligence-Android-master\app\build` directory manually

Answer (score 2):

These steps usually help me:

- Close Android Studio
- Kill OpenJDK processes
- Open Android Studio again

Answer (score 1):

Go to windows explorer, navigate manually to the path, and delete it using windows as opposed to android studio.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the project: go to build menu -> clean project. It usually deletes generated and intermediate files which may cause the error you faced